# How to pass param in url using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.6.7. I want to pass param in url. My expected url is: http://demo.jegeachi.com/tolets/search?page=2

but url is look like:
http://demo.jegeachi.com/tolets/search/%2526page%253D2

My code is:

```
 if ($total_page > 2):
                    $current_page = 0;
                    if(isset($this->params['url']['page'])){
                      $current_page = $this->params['url']['page'];
                    }
                        ?>
                       <?php if($current_page>1){
                         $url = 'page='.--$current_page;
                        ?>
                       <li><a href="<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'tolets', 'action' => 'search', $url)); ?>"> &laquo;</a></li>
                      <?php }?> 

                        <?php for ($page = 1; $page <= $total_page; $page++):
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($page == $current_page) { ?>
                                <li><span><?php echo $page; ?> </span></li>
                            <?php } else {
                               $url = '&page='.$page;
                             ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'tolets', 'action' => 'search', $url)); ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php endfor;
                        ?>
                        <?php if($current_page<$total_page){
                        $url = 'page='.++$current_page;
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'tolets', 'action' => 'search', $url)); ?>">&raquo;</a></li>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php endif;
                        ?>
```

I also tried to use urlencode but no luck.

Comment: Is this a `view(.ctp)` code

Comment: seems you are trying to paginate. Maybe you have your reasons but are you aware that cake comes with built in paginator component and helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also you can use

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Title', array(
    'controller' => 'tolets',
    'action' => 'search','?page=2')
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a view code

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Title', array(
    'controller' => 'tolets',
    'action' => 'search',
    '?' => array('page' => 2))
);
?>
```

It will output

```
<a href="/tolets/search?page=2">Title</a>
```